# ConcurrentDictionary InvalidOperationException c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, list, asp.net-web-api

this is the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
>       at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
>         at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
>
>           at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>            at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()
>
>            at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>   Blockquote

I use the static Dictionary for web api

this is my class that i use for my web api :

```
public class UsersSecureProvider
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<short, List<UserSecure>> _Users = new ConcurrentDictionary<short, List<UserSecure>>();

    public bool Add(short Group, UserSecure Message)
    {
        try
        {
            var GetList = GetByKey(Group);

            if (GetList != null)
            {
                GetList.Add(Message);
                return Update(Group, GetList, GetList);
            }
            else
            {
                GetList = new List<UserSecure>();
                GetList.Add(Message);
                return Add(Group, GetList);
            }
        }
        catch { }

        return false;
    }

    private bool Add(short key, List<UserSecure> SendUser)
    {
        return _Users.TryAdd(key, SendUser);
    }

    public bool Remove(short Key)
    {
        List<UserSecure> listremove;
        return _Users.TryRemove(Key, out listremove);
    }

    public List<UserSecure> GetByKey(short Group)
    {
        var listView = new List<UserSecure>();
        if (_Users != null)
        {
            var getList = _Users.TryGetValue(Group, out listView);
        }

        return listView;
    }

    public bool Update(short Group, List<UserSecure> oldlist, List<UserSecure> newlist)
    {
        return _Users.TryUpdate(Group, newlist, oldlist);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _Users.Clear();
    }

    public ConcurrentDictionary<short, List<UserSecure>> GetAll()
    {
        return _Users;
    }

    public bool UpdateListByUser(short Group, List<UserSecure> newlist)
    {
        var OldList = GetByKey(Group);
        return _Users.TryUpdate(Group, newlist, OldList);
    }
}
```

And I call the class

```
 var _providers = new UsersSecureProvider();

        List<UserSecure> GetAll = _providers.GetByKey(1);

        if (GetAll != null && GetAll.Any() && GetAll.Where(w => w.UserID == UserID && w.Key == UniqueSecure).Count() > 0)
        {
            result = true;
        }
        else
        {
                _providers.Add(1, new UserSecure { UserID = UserID, Key = UniqueSecure });
        }
```

why do i receive this error exception?

thank you.

Comment: Which one of the methods is causing the exception?

Comment: where you call `Count()` function?

Comment: Normally this error occurres  when you're add/removing items within an iteration.  This can be fix with, instead iterating the collection, iterating a copy of the collection. like: `_Users.ToArray()`

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, problem not in code that provide OP, but in some outer: somewhere used `Count()` on some collection, i not sure that problem with dictionary

Comment: @Ori, where you call function `Where(...).Count()`?

Comment: @OriBenDavid, add this you your post

Comment: I add the code thanks you can help me?

Comment: do you call this in web api actions?

Comment: Yes, when the user delete,update,select. i chacked secure key the user

Comment: do you get errors always or just some times?

Comment: Somtimes not always.

Comment: all because sometimes two actions call one try `add` and second do `where`

Comment: How can i fix this? maybe i add lock object?

Comment: Think first a bit about what you want to achieve. Presumably you want more than getting rid of your exception, you want your code to actually work. You first check if an item exists in your dictionary where `w.UserID == UserID && w.Key == UniqueSecure`. Then, if it doesn't exist, you add it. You have concurrent accesses to your dictionary. What happens if two processes are running? Both check the dictionary for the specific item. Both see it isn't there. And then, both add it. Your code cannot work. Think about something that can work first.

Comment: You're right .. So what can we do about it?

Comment: I need chack user exists and another procsess add to Dictionary

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
List<UserSecure> GetAll = _providers.GetByKey(1);
```

Returns a reference to the underlying collection. That same reference to a list which is probably being modified via one of the other WebAPI actions you have. You cannot both enumerate and modify the `List<T>`.

Instead, create a new `List<T>` and enumerate it:

```
List<UserSecure> GetAll = _providers.GetByKey(1).ToList();
```

Comment: in this case - not work `else` branch where try add element to list

Comment: @Grundy He's only enumerating it. He's *modifying* the dictionary, not the list.

Comment: Thanks for help. but why do ToList()?  It has been on the list

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, you right! confused _providers_ with gettted list.

Comment: @Ori Because you cant enumerate and modify the same list concurrently

Comment: @OriBenDavid, `ToList` just return _new_ list

Comment: U want create new list and update ConcurrentDictionary?

Comment: @OriBenDavid, nope, create _new_ list needed to avoid enumerationg and adding same list

Comment: Ok all code is good? i add ToList() and avoid enumeration error?

Comment: @OriBenDavid for provided code this should be enouhg

Answer (score -1):

If your application is multi threading it is recomanded to use semaphore. For example

```
private static object _sync = new object();
public List<UserSecure> GetByKey(short Group)
{
    lock(_sync)
    {
        var listView = new List<UserSecure>();
        if (_Users != null)
        {
            var getList = _Users.TryGetValue(Group, out listView);
        }

        return listView;
    }
}
```

Comment: [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) already use something like this inside. Also how your sample helps with problem OP in `where` and `count` functions?

Comment: First of all what is the line from your code which crash?

Comment: ask OP about this :-D

Comment: In this case I would use semaphore for all methods just for testing. And if this work I would replace `ConcurrentDictionary` with something else, maybe a normal `Dictinonary`.

Comment: but why you need do this manually if this already implemented? :-) if you look to errors - you can see that all hapens in `Count` functions called on `WhereIterator` that return `Where` function, that called on some `List<T>`. In code that provide OP - you not see any of this function. So problem not in `ConcurrentDictionary`

Comment: Yes, but it call `Count` function in its implementation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93233/discussion-between-grundy-and-roroinpho21).

Comment: I call Method GetByKey